# It's been lovely having you here. (Is this sentence said when it's almost time for someone to leave a place?)

Tags: interpretation

It's been lovely having you here. (Is this sentence said when it's almost time for someone to leave a place?)

> It has been lovely having you here.

The tense is has+pp (present perfect), which means something happend in the past and continued until now or finished now. So the person was there in the past and now he/she is going to leave and the conversation partner says "It has been lovely having you here."?

Comment: I can be said at any time during a visit but, as you say, it is usually said shortly before the guest leaves. It can also be used to soften the blow before politely asking somebody to leave "It's been lovely having you here, but I have a big meeting tomorrow, so I really need to go to bed now".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

If you were half way through a visit with someone and they said this, it would probably be because they've taken a moment to think about the time spent so far.  So in that case they're still referring to the past, i.e. the time between now and when you arrived, but that doesn't necessarily mean you're about to leave.

That said, I'd say it's most commonly used when your time there is over.